# Nested kay value pair in Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, function, lodash

I am doing a function which should return an object.
In this case, `query` is the initial object, and what I want is adding more key/values to `query` for example `query.location.city` but it looks like it is not possible just nesting with `.` and assign a value.

How can achieve this?

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let queryBuilder = function (obj) {

  let query = {};

  // City
  if(_.has(obj, 'city')) {
    query.location.city = obj.city ;
  }

  // Country
  if(_.has(obj, 'country')) {
     query.location.country_code = obj.country;
  }

  return query;

};

module.exports = queryBuilder;
```

Comment: well there is no `location` so you would need to add it. `query.location = query.location || {}`

Answer (score 4):

You would need to create the location obj.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let queryBuilder = function (obj) {

  let query = {};

  // City
  if(_.has(obj, 'city')) {
    query.location = {
      city: obj.city
    };
  }

  return query;

};

module.exports = queryBuilder;
```